# Convert XHTML to XAML FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, xaml, xhtml, converters, flowdocument

Does anybody invent a workable converter program that can convert XHTML file to FlowDocument xml file?

I need this because my XHTML document have nested  tag and it make my converter xslt thrown exceptions.

any ideas?

I appericate all replys and your times.

Best regards
-Ariso

Comment: Please rephrase your question.

Comment: @Ariso: I didn't add another -1, but Electro is right in that we need more information to respond. For example, could you show an example of the code you're using, the exceptions that XSLT is giving you, etc?

Comment: -1 voters are discouraging the community, I lost my interest in answering because ops don't care to up vote and stupid down voters are driving me nuts, this question has nothing wrong in it to get two minus votes. Op is clearly asking for alternative, not solution to his existing problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In advance of the revisions requested above:

Microsoft has a [demo of how to convert XAML to XHTML and vice-versa](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972129.aspx). This should get you most of the way to where you're going.

Comment: Great. let me have a look. It may help me learn another way to convert XHTML to XAML. -- flowdocument xmal